# Let f(x) = x+(2)/x. Rewrite f(x+h)-f(x)/h as a single reduced fraction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x) = x+(2)/x$. Rewrite $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ as a single reduced fraction.
My answer is $x^2 + xh - 2 / x (x+h)$

Am I right?

Also, what is the best way to think of problem such as this?

Should always consider the difference quotient the input?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle f(x)=(x)+\frac2{(x)}, f(x+h)=(x+h)+\frac2{(x+h)}$

I've put all $x$s inside parenthesis for better clarity

So, $\displaystyle f(x+h)-f(x)=(x+h)+\frac2{(x+h)}-\left((x)+\frac2{(x)}\right)$

$\displaystyle=h+\frac2{x+h}-\frac2x=h+\frac{2\{x-(x+h)\}}{x(x+h)}=\cdots$